# Rotate TextView without cut off text

Tags: android

i'm trying to rotate a TextView, but my text gets cut off by the bounds. But the text is rotated. 
I'm not using this for an animation or some sort. It's just static, design-wise :)

I have a RotatedTextView where i do this:

```
public class RotatedTextView extends TextView
@Override
public void onDraw(Canvas canvas)
{
    canvas.save(); 
    float py = this.getHeight()/2.0f;
    float px = this.getWidth()/2.0f;
    px = py = 0;
    canvas.rotate(this.degrees, px, py); 
    super.onDraw(canvas); 
    canvas.restore(); 
}
```

Here's how it is looking now:

[image]

[*Orginial source*](http://up.belgianlotus.be/files/screenshot20110926at10.50.07.png)

Can anyone help me solve this issue ?

Thanks !

Comment: why not just animate the textview and set the duration as 0. so it wont appear as animation. I dont think canvas.roate will show the full etxt as the bounds are still the same. And whatever is outside the bounds wont be shown.

Comment: I tried it with the animation, but even when setting duration to 0, you still see the text switching from horizontal to x degrees.

Answer (score 0):

Try add padding to the textview. That should make the canvas remain inside the bounds. Or you might need to put the height of the view accordingly.

Comment: I ended up redoing the design with no rotated textviews :)