# rotate textview with its background view

Tags: android, rotation, textview, imageview

I've customized textview but its just rotating its text not its whole view. and I don't want to use animation because I'm dragging textveiw as well so moving animated textview shows weird result, so sticking to onDraw/draw, plus overriding draw is nothing doing special.

```
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    // TO-DO Auto-generated method stub
    canvas.save();
    canvas.rotate(rotationAngle, rotationW, rotationH);
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    canvas.restore();
}
```

Same problem [Rotate TextView without cut off text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7552880/rotate-textview-without-cut-off-text?rq=1)?

how can I rotate the whole view along text??

Answer (score 0):

If you want to **rotate** the **view** use [**View**.**setRotation**()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setRotation(float)).